# Attach a two handed weapon to UE4 character

Tags: animation, rigging, game-engine, unreal-engine

I want to make a animation set of a two handed sword, but i don't know how to attach both hands to the weapon, and i dont know how to retarget it to Unreal Engine if necessary need to use more bones, as UE4 manequim skeleton will not have these "extra bones".

I am using the default UE4 mannequin file that you download for Blender, so all main bones are already named (of course, it is the Unreal Skeleton), [downloaded here](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Character_from_Blender_to_UE4)

Comment: "and i dont know how to retarget it to Unreal Engine if necessary need to use more bones, as UE4 manequim skeleton will not have these "extra bones". " This has me worrying. Maybe watch some more tutorials. You dont add a sword bone to your character to add a sword. You will have to create a socket in UE4 to attach the weapon to. Your animation should be provided like an "Air Guitar" without the sword. This allows to attach and detach the weapon from the socket in realtime ingame.
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Content/Types/SkeletalMeshes/Sockets/index.html

Comment: Yeah. I know this now. For me, this was going to be very weird, but it doesnt.